# How to modify Airfoil thickness

Tags: airfoils

I'm writing a fusion360 adding to model windmill blades. My first goal is to model the **NREL Phase IV** in which the airfoils (S809) definitions come with ***thickness*** and also ***span station*** (wich I¿dont know what is):

[image]

Right now, I'm able to calculate the max thickness. as shown in the next picture as the difference between the max point on the upper surface(y-direction), and the min point(y-direction) of the lower surface. I'm not really sure if this is correct, and then I don´t know how to modify the entire airfoil with the new thickness definition in the table above.

[image]